Find the minimal polynomial of $T^{-1}.$
I was thinking of the following question:
Suppose $V$ is finite dimensional and $T\in \mathcal{L}(V)$ has minimal polynomial $4 + 5z -6z^2 -7z^3 + 2z^4 + z^5.$ Find the minimal polynomial of $T^{-1}.$
Then I found the following similar question here If I have the minimal polynomial for $T$, is the minimal polynomial for$ T^{-1}$ the inverse of that polynomial?, but I was wondering why we are pretty sure that the solution given there will give us actually the minimal polynomial of $T^{-1}.$
Can someone clarify this to me please?

Perhaps multiply through by $(T^{-1})^5 $ and divide by $4$?

the eigenvalues  of the inverse matrix are the reciprocals of the eigenvalues!

When given a transformation $T$ and a polynomial $p$, the question of whether $p$ is the minimal polynomial comes down to two questions: 1. Is it true that $p(T) = 0$, and 2. Is it true that, if $q$ has lesser degree than $p$, then $q(T) \neq 0$? Are you able to answer question 1, from the link? That is, are you able to show that $T^{-1}$ indeed satisfies $p(T^{-1}) = 0$?

I do not think I am able to answer the second question @TheoBendit

The arguments below and in the linked answer show that, given any polynomial $p$ such that $p(T)=0$, there is a polynomial $q$ such that $q(T^{-1})=0$ with the same degree as $p$. So, the minimal polynomial of $T$ has degree greater than or equal to the minimal polynomial of $T^{-1}$. Same argument, with $T$ and $T^{-1}$ interchanged shows the reverse inequality, so the degrees of the minimal popynomials must be the same. So, the constructed monic polynomial $q$, satisfying $q(T^{-1})=0$, with degree equal to the minimal polynomial of $T$ must be the minimal polynomial of $T^{-1}$.

Hints:
Suppose $p(x) = p_0+p_1x+...+p_{m-1}x^{m-1}+x^m$ is a monic polynomial with $p_o \neq 0$, and $p(A) = 0$, then note that $q(y) = {1 \over p_0}+{p_{m-1} \over p_0}y+...+{p_2 \over p_0} y + y^m$ is a monic polynomial (of the same degree) that satisfies $q(A^{-1}) = 0$.
Using the above, show that the degrees of the minimal polynomials of $A$ and $A^{-1}$ are the same.
Based on Theo's comment, another hint: Note that $A = (A^{-1})^{-1}$.

Why the downvote?

I was going to put this same comment a couple of hours ago (as the source of the +1), but I think I understand having re-read the question. The OP already has an answer that indicates something like this, and seems to be struggling with the detail. I suspect it's in showing that the polynomial is indeed minimal (which your hint briskly addresses in the final line), but given that they already have the over-arching structure and are struggling with the details, a hint may not be appropriate. Of course, all of this is a guess, as I didn't provide the downvote.
